# ios 9 and NSAppTransportSecurity

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, xcode7

There is a problem with iOS 9 and work with the server. 
I info.plist set:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

When you run the application through Xcode, everything is fine. Work with the server takes place perfectly. But as soon as I stop the application and try to run it by simply clicking on the icon in the simulator. The network stops working. The same problem when I send the application to the Review in TestFlight. The application is installed, but the network stops working again.

Xcode 7.0 (7a220)
iOS 9.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it's not working? I tested it and everything is fine.

**Possible actions**:

Having a Debug mode enabled, build your app, run it from Xcode and make sure that you *don't* get an *App Transport Security* error:

`App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure.`

when launching it from Xcode using your simulator. Now find a *DEVICE_CODE* of the same very simulator

`(Hint: it will be one of these ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/. The easiest way to find this code from Xcode is to go Window->Devices)`

and open with **Console** its log file:

```
~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<DEVICE_CODE>/system.log
```

Clear the history (just in case you can launch your app from Xcode once again and make sure your output is getting into the log-file you opened, and that you still don't get *App Transport Security* error in there).

Now launch your app from the simulator and check if you have any errors related to *App Transport Security* in the log.

For me I don't have any if none of them I get when working from Xcode.

==================================

**P.S.**:

It's strongly recommended to not set an *NSAllowsArbitraryLoads* to *true*, you'd rather want to achieve the desired result with:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the first option (Possible actions :) not to no avail. Not any errors in the log file does not appear, everything works fine. But after stopping the application Xcode network is not working again.

What touching NSExceptionDomains this method also leads to the same problem.

Comment: Is there a reason for you to be sure that the cause of the problem is *NSAppTransportSecurity* then? You said there was no errors from it in console.

Comment: If you have a Mac running 10.11 you can use the new `nscurl` command with the `--ats-diagnostics option`. This will take a look at the service you are connecting to and tell you what settings you need to adjust to connect while leaving the shields up as much as possible.

Comment: I can not understand what could be the cause. Also available is now my server with https and TLC v1.2 requests but also do not pass it on to the iOS 9. iOS 8 everything is fine.

Comment: Hmm. NSAppTransportSecurity is known to cause problems for *HTTP* requests. For *HTTPS* it should not block anything. Perhaps it makes sense for you to add more Tags for your question (e.g. to have *nsurlrequest*, *afnetworking*) and to try to search the problem where @macshome suggests

Comment: I can not understand. How does my project compiles fine and everything works. But as soon as I unplug it from Xcode it stops working. How is it possible?

Comment: @MiRiNMan I just want to confirm whether this answer helps or not. Your last comment seems to show that it isn't, but somehow you accepted it.

Comment: @Willy I think it's worth to underline that my answer was not supposed to solve a problem. It rather lists steps to make sure that the problem is in some other place rather than described in the question. It would be a great headache if networking worked differently in simulator and on the device. Regards.

Comment: I don't really understand how can I put URL in <key>yourserver.com</key> if I somehow have URL like this www.abc.co.kr.

Comment: @Inuyasha Your URL is _abc.co.kr_, so it should be _<key>abc.co.kr</key>_ That way you'll get all the endpoints like _abc.co.kr/foo/bar_ working.

Answer (score 2):

It should be done like this, you need to add in your Plist the following records 
[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)

It is lazy so your frameworks have access to Internet

NSAppTransportSecurity <- Type Dictionary

NSAllowsArbitraryLoads <- Type Boolean Value YES

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, just follow the below steps:

1. App Transport security settings.
2. Allow Arbitrary loads.
3. Exception domains and the domain/host reference.

[image]

Note: This issue happens because your project settings does not allow by default any cross site scripting references. Hence, it blocks any service calls that goes outside of your app.