# Can't load my web view with an http URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a problem in loading in my web view
This is my code:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://www.google.com.eg";

//    NSString *urlString = @"http://fatima.ibtdi.work";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_fatimaView loadRequest:urlRequest];}
```

It works on Google but doesn't work on the another link.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri no error just blank view

Comment: Are you added  NSAppTransportSecurity in your .plist.

Comment: no..can you help me? @RajeshDharani

Comment: Check below link https://stackoverflow.com/a/32885488/5184217

Comment: http connections are not allowed in webview without setting the ATS in your plist file!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios 9 and NSAppTransportSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663122/ios-9-and-nsapptransportsecurity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to add some App Transport Security Settings to your Info plist try this
[image]

Any HTTP loading in a web view will require adding the domain to these settings.

Comment: NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Comment: Are you using http for your url or did you change it to https? Changing it to https would cause this error

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, he must had forgot to add `NSAppTransportSecurity`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

in your `info.plist` because your link "http://fatima.ibtdi.work" is not secured by SSL, so you have to add `NSAppTransportSecurity` in your `info.plist` file. IOS manage the link if the link is secured with SSL certificates else it block transportation from device to web.

Hope this helps you.